# How to query multiple json nodes?

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I have the following json:

```
{
  "key445" : {
    "text" : "cat",
    "id" : 445
  },
  "key457" : {
    "text" : "mouse",
    "id" : 457
  },
  "key458" : {
    "text" : "rodent",
    "id" : 458
  }
}
```

I am trying extract `text` and `id` into a `List<TextIdentifier>` (a class with string and an int), or even separately into `List<string>` and `List<int>`.

I read the text into JObject using `JObject.Parse` method.  However, I can't figure out how to get to the text and id nodes.  I've tried the following but it returns nothing.

```
var textTokens = o.SelectTokens("/*/text");
var idTokens = o.SelectTokens("/*/id");
```

How can I get to the tokens I want?

Comment: Any reason for parsing into a `JObject` rather than parsing into `Dictionary<string, TextIdentifier>` which I suspect would just work immediately?

Comment: @JonSkeet No reason, I just don't know how to do it.  JObject seemed like a good way to debug this.

Comment: Right. So if `TextIdentifier` has writable properties for `Text` and `Id`, that's all you need to do :)

Comment: @JonSkeet My issue is finding the right JsonPath query to extract these tokens from json.  Once I get them, I could definitely write them to an object.

Comment: My point is that you don't need to use JsonPath at all. Just convert the whole of your object to a `Dictionary<string, TextIdentifier>` and then if you only need the values, just use the `Values` property. Unless you need them in the order of the JSON file, which would be quite fragile. (Adding a sample now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just convert the whole JSON into a `Dictionary<string, TextIdentifier>` instead of trying to use JsonPath at all:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public class TextIdentifier
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"Id: {Id}; Text: {Text}";
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, TextIdentifier>>(json);

        foreach (var pair in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key} => {pair.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
key445 => Id: 445; Text: cat
key457 => Id: 457; Text: mouse
key458 => Id: 458; Text: rodent
```

If you don't care about the keys, you can use `dictionary.Values.ToList()` to get a `List<TextIdentifier>` although you shouldn't rely on the order of them.

Comment: Wow, that is actually perfect.  I wish I could upvote more.